# How to turn a stream of integer into java.awt.Point?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need to read a list of integers from stdin and turn them into java.awt.Point(x,y) array.

The format of the input is x y x y x y ...

I can do it the non-stream way like this,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
String[] input = scanner.next().split("\\s+");
Point[] points = new Point[input.length/2];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length/2; i++) {
    points[i] = new Point(Integer.parseInt(input[2*i]), 
        Integer.parseInt(input[2*i+1]));
}
```

But how do I do it using stream? I get stuck at `map()`.

```
List<Point> points = Arrays.stream(scanner.next().split("\\s+"))
    .map(Integer::parseInt).map(??).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to take two items from the stream in each step, and since you don't know what will be in the stream in advance, you can do it in two steps:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");

List<Integer> integers = Arrays.stream(scanner.next().split("\\s+"))
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Point> points = IntStream.range(1, integers.size())
        .filter(x -> x % 2 == 1) // in order to not repeat elements
        .mapToObj((i) -> new Point(integers.get(i-1), integers.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(points);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2], java.awt.Point[x=3,y=4], java.awt.Point[x=5,y=6], java.awt.Point[x=7,y=8]]
```

Comment: Would it make a difference if I know the number of integer in stdin in advance?

Comment: @user5245796 if you have the list of Integers you can skip the first part (which reads and transforms it from strings to integers) and go directly to the second.

Comment: I know how many integers in advance but don't know what they are until they are read from stdin. Guess I still need two steps.  Thank you.